# Не масштабируется svg-элемент, созданный Ангуляром

Tags: css, svg, angular2

Как известно, svg-элемент с заданным `viewbox` и размерами должен астоматически масштабироваться к размерам, прописанным в стилях.

Например, возьмём круг в области 200*200 и поместим его в `div` размером 100*100. Svg масштабируется до требуемого размера 100*100, весь круг видимый:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="99" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

А теперь поместим эту разметку в шаблон компонента Angular 2:

```
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="99" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

При тех же стилях получится такое отображение:

[image: Скриншот]

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?
Требуется, чтобы svg нормально масштабировалось.

Полный пример: http://plnkr.co/edit/jNJNJLo8ygVcp9SIVcDx?p=preview

---

Интересно, что если выделить этот `svg`-элемент в devtools и выполнить скрипт

```
$0.outerHTML = $0.outerHTML
```

то элемент отобразится ожидаемым способом.

---

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/37701914/4928642)

Comment: Пость ответ :-)

Comment: @Grundy, запостил. Я обыскался уже, что ж оно не работает, а всё так просто оказалось...

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37701914/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
> ```

Для ангуляра требуется верно указывать имя свойства с большой буквой `B`:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8987

PS: Оригинальный [ответ на enSO](//stackoverflow.com/a/37702208/4928642) от [Robert Longson](//stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).